# CloudFormation: Pass List to Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation script that creates a Lambda Function for RDS backups.  How can I pass a list of servers from the CloudFormation template to the lambda function?  Right now they are hard-coded, and I don't think that is ideal.

**CloudFormation Script**:

```
{ "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Parameters": {
    "ruleName": {
      "Description": "Name for CloudWatch Rule.",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "cronSchedule": {
      "Description": "Cron Schedule Expression",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "cron(0 05 * * ? *)"
    },
    "bucketName" : {
      "Description": "S3 Bucket storing the lambda script",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "lambdaTimeout": {
      "Description": "Timeout for Lambda",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "3"
    },
    "instanceList":{
      "Description": "",
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "cloudWatchRule": {
      "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
      "DependsOn": "lambdaFunction",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "Cron Schedule",
        "Name": {
          "Ref": "ruleName"
        },
        "ScheduleExpression": {
          "Ref": "cronSchedule"
        },
        "State": "ENABLED",
        "Targets": [
          {
            "Arn":{
              "Fn::GetAtt": ["lambdaFunction","Arn"]
            },
            "Id": {
              "Ref": "lambdaFunction"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "lambdaFunction": {
      "Type":"AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "DependsOn": [
        "lambdaRdsBackupRole",
        "rdsBackupExecutionPolicy"
      ],
      "Properties":{
        "Code": {
          "S3Bucket": {
            "Ref": "bucketName"
          },
          "S3Key": "lambdaFunctions/rdsBackup.zip"
        },
        "Role": {
          "Fn::GetAtt": ["lambdaRdsBackupRole", "Arn"]
        },
        "Handler": "rdsBackup.lambda_handler",
        "Environment":{
          "Variables": {
            "dbInstances": {
              "Ref": "instanceList"
            }
          }
        },
        "Runtime": "python3.6",
        "MemorySize": 128,
        "Timeout": {
          "Ref": "lambdaTimeout"
        }
      }
    },
    "lambdaRdsBackupRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/"
      }
    },
    "rdsBackupExecutionPolicy": {
      "DependsOn": [
        "lambdaRdsBackupRole"
      ],
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "lambdaRdsBackupRolePolicy",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "lambdaRdsBackupRole"
          }
        ],
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "rds:AddTagsToResource",
                "rds:DeleteDBSnapshot"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:*:*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "rds:ListTagsForResource",
                "rds:CreateDBSnapshot"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:rds:*:*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "rds:DescribeDBSnapshots"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I added this section in, but I'm not quite sure if it's right, and if it is I'm still not quite sure where to go from here:

```
 "Environment":{
          "Variables": {
            "dbInstances": {
              "Ref": "instanceList"
            }
          }
        },
```

**Lambda Function**:

```
import boto3
import datetime


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Connecting to RDS")
    client = boto3.client('rds')

    # Instance to backup
    dbInstances = ['testdb', 'testdb2']

    for dbInstance in dbInstances:
        print("RDS snapshot backups started at %s...\n" % datetime.datetime.now())

        for snapshot in client.describe_db_snapshots(DBInstanceIdentifier=dbInstance, MaxRecords=50)['DBSnapshots']:
            try:
                createTs = snapshot['SnapshotCreateTime'].replace(tzinfo=None)
                if createTs < datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30):
                    print("Deleting snapshot id:", snapshot['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])
                    client.delete_db_snapshot(
                        DBSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot['DBSnapshotIdentifier']
                    )
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error: "+ str(e))
                pass

        client.create_db_snapshot(
            DBInstanceIdentifier=dbInstance,
            DBSnapshotIdentifier=dbInstance+'{}'.format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H")),
            Tags=[
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'dbInstance'

                },
            ]
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do this. A few that come to mind are listed below.

1) If you are set on adding the variable into the cloud formation template I would add the python script inline to the cloudformation template and you can pass the array in as a variable to the template. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html

2) You can create an environment variable for the lambda function and every time you execute it (either console or command line) you can update the environment variable with the new data base instances. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-environment

3) You can use something like API Gateway and tie it to a lambda function. You could pass the array in a POST request to the lambda function. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

Without knowing your end goal it is hard to recommend one of these over the other.